# 50k into 24 month 1.15% p.a. term deposit, did I make a mistake?

Tags: investing, australia, short-term, house

Context:
I'm 23 y/o, live with family for obvious financial reasons. While I do pay for all the pet care/internet and some communal food/fuel I obviously am still mooching a lot from my parents.

The amount I'm saving doing this is crazy. From living alone and working full time I would spend 70% of pay-check on fundamental necessities. Now thats down to 20%. Which was enough for me to save 50k in a couple of years.

I know that money just sitting in a savings account is a bit of a waste so I really wanted to do SOMETHING with it. I looked into buying an investment property but while I have enough for the downpayment, I am paid minimum wage and I also reduced my hours so that I could study while working. So I didn't think I was earning enough to confidently maintain mortgage payments.

I spent a lot of time thinking about if and where I should invest. Asked some early beginner questions in this stack too. My savings goal is just to maximise money so that after I finish studying in a couple years, I can be well off enough to apply for jobs anywhere knowing I would have the financial capability to make a deposit on a house in that area. I may not immediately buy, I just want to have the capability to do so. Because this could happen as early as just 2 years from now, there is a good chance the investment would only be for 2 years. Unfortunately the only style of investing I was comfortable with would be long term, where my plan would be to simply select a bunch of companies from various index funds, and then let the money sit there for 10+ years. Anyway, in the end I could never muster the courage to invest anything, since its only for 2 years, holds a fair amount of risk and I know I am a complete novice, I didn't feel confident enough to make the right decisions.

Months passed with the money just sitting in savings and I have finally just thrown it all into a 2 year term deposit at my local bank (National Australia Bank) because I clearly wasn't doing anything else with the money. 1.15% is tiny, but its actually better than what the other banks in my area offer. Just 1.15% definitely still feels like a waste. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Was this a mistake?  I wouldn't begin to offer judgement since I have no clue what other  choices are available in Australia.  What I would suggest is that time permitting, you begin the process of becoming financially  literate so that you are no longer a complete novice and you can begin to make the right decisions.  Start reading.

Comment: The "cash rate" at the Reserve Bank of Australia is 0.75%, and the inflation rate in Dec 2019 was 1.8%.  Thus, I'd say that a 1.15% TD is reasonable for a short term deposit.

Comment: Just a quick search online I found a term deposit rate of 2.05% over 24 months and many others around 1.5%. Maybe you didn't shop around enough!

Comment: @Jesse Not sure if you're still around, but you've got the money out now! You've probably had a lot else going on the past two years, but it would be great to hear how you view your savings now and whether you've grown more confident in the meantime!

Comment: @nanoman I'm still around. So the 2 years is over and I've pocketed my 1k from the term deposit. Still don't work that much but upped my savings total to 75k. My timeline has changed, 2 years was optimistic. I deferred my computer-science degree for a year ending soon and when I return I would likely take it as slow as possible, I've done some side things. I was a paid fitness partner in my down time for a year and am making some videos about the champion I'm good at in a game. My views on savings is similar, might be slightly more confident. Yet again, I'm figuring out where to put my money

Comment: @Jesse Good to hear your progress.

Answer (score 9):

The most important thing you did was have the opportunity and discipline to save a significant amount at a young age; this was not a mistake. You might have earned a little more in the next 2 years in a more sophisticated investment, but even if you'd got a great yield of 5%, that is only $4k difference. And if you'd made some unsuitable high-risk investment as a novice, you might have lost all $50k.

Your $51k (plus what you continue to save) will be there in 2 years for you to make good decisions with based on all the knowledge you will have by then -- whether for an emergency fund, home purchase, and/or long-term investments. The savings habit you've established will be far more valuable over your life than 2 years' return on $50k.

I salute you and see no mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

Since Australia is possibly at risk of a recession due to a growing slowdown in China, the two-year bank deposit is a very good investment.

However, a two-year government-bond in a brokerage account could show a gain in value if there were a recession. In fact a two-year government-bond in a brokerage account could be leveraged if such economic views are held. Or a leveraged government-bond ETF might be found. Another choice is gold but probably not gold-mining stocks.

Or if the Australian currency were hedged with a sell of the AUD/USD then the position could receive a small rollover interest, probably 1/4 of one percent, on the leveraged amount.

Other choices, if not expecting recession, are bank stocks, telecommunications stocks, and real estate stocks. Basically, this is an equity-income category.

Comment: The probability of recession has already been priced into all of these by professionals. Would you really advise a novice to try to beat them at market timing/arbitrage?

Comment: The news is daily. The epidemic in China could be increasing or decreasing. I mentioned two different economic views but I kept the second view as non-export related.

Comment: Risk of recession? Leveraged government-bond ETFs? Gold?  Hedging a leveraged  AUD/USD position?  Stock sectors to invest in?  The OP is a noob wondering about basic cash equivalents.  This is sledgehammer advice for a person who has no clue what a tack is.  KYC.

Comment: I suggested a two-year government-bond instead of the two-year bank deposit. The two-year government-bond can have an intermediate gain accounted if interest rates decline. And risk-of-recession is in the news in Australia. Certainly more discussion followed.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a big mistake, but being australian your options are limited unless you are willing to take currency risk.

I.e. I have some of my funds in a financial institution in switzerland paying me 8% in daily available funds, but they only accept deposits in EUR, USD or GBP - so one woul have to leave the australian dollar or hedge this risk, which add significant complication for someone not fluent with forex operations.

Given from what australia looks like from a european perspective you may be better buying gold - there are chances all major economies will get into some higher inflation brackets soonish, stocks are overpriced, australia what I hear has a terribly overprived real estate market. Which means there really are not a lot of options - and your interest rate will already with that inflation result in a net loss of purchasing power.